# by the time you ..., you [present simple] or [present perfect]

Tags: grammar, tense

I came across this sentence in my textbook:

> By the time you have enough money and time, you are quite old.

I think "you are quite old" can also be "you have got/been quite old"(and it's even better), is that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without question, *[by then] you **have been** quite old* is syntactically invalid. And in my opinion, *...you **have got** quite old* is idiomatically unnatural.

The reason it's "unnatural" is because both Simple Present *(you **are**)* AND Present Perfect *(you **have got / gotten**)* in such contexts are "high register" dated / formal / literary usages. But ***got / gotten*** here is relatively "low register" / dialectal, so there's a clash.

I wouldn't really have a problem with *[by then] you **have become** quite old*, but I'm sure most native speakers would use an explicit Future Tense verb to refer to that point in future time...

> *[by then] you **will be** quite old*.

---

[Here's a chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=by%20then%20you%20are%2Cby%20then%20you%20will%20be&year_start=1850&year_end=2019&corpus=27&smoothing=20) (Google Books *English **Fiction*** corpus) showing how this kind of "Present-as-Future" usage has declined over the past century and more. It's still "valid", but I suggest *learners* should avoid using it themselves.

[image]